# The file is no longer located

Tags: windows-7, file-management, file-transfer

I want to move a couple files from an external hard disk, I can see the files and I can see how much space they occupy on the volume.

If I try to move, rename or open them I obtain this error prompt: "Could not find this item. the file is no longer located in [filepath] Verify the items location and try again."

The files don't have any extension and I can't rename them. Trying command prompt commands on them always yields incorrect syntax errors.

Is there a way I can deal with this problem?

Comment: It sounds like a corrupt filesystem.  there is a really good chance the files no longer even exist on the disk.

Comment: I encountered this today, the issue was the folder had a trailing space (folder was created using Git bash and when trying to delete from windows I was getting this issue). Once I removed the trailing space while creating the folder from Git bash, the issue no longer exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspected the files were somehow corrupt but I could edit them without any problem using a different OS (Debian Linux), so I renamed the files adding the .txt extension and moved them to a different location and Windows now can handle them without problems. If ever, renaming the plain-text files to txt led to losing all the line breaks, but I'm fine with it.